# jQuery Validate field where Name attribute contains square brackets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am attempting to validate a form that contains fields with name attributes containing square brackets [].   It's a requirement that I cannot change the name attribute to something else, and it just seems messy trying to validate via ID or ClassName..

How would I go about validating the w as the following example?  As of now it does not work (makes my entire page completely dissappear due to an error.

```
$("#loginForm").validate({
    rules: {

        login[username]: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {

        login[username]: {
            required: "Please provide an email",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: using `login[username]` inside a javascript object is not valid syntax. you could use quotes around it and make it valid `"login[username]"` but I'm not sure if that would solve your problem.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just `"login[username]" : {`

Comment: Yeah you guys were right, I wasn't sure that the quotes would be OK but they are in fact.  If one of you wants to make this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using `login[username]` inside a javascript object is not valid syntax. Use quotes around it to make it valid `"login[username]"`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could do something like this instead...

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="login[username]" class="myRule" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.myRule').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Please provide an email",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    });

});
```

Alternatively, you do not need to add or use classes, just use the proper selector to target the appropriate input element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name=login\\[username\\]]').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Please provide an email",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    });

});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules